# Build of SLR lens vs point-and-shoot lens

Tags: lens, point-and-shoot, slr

There are point-and-shoot cameras that offer large range of angle of view. For example, Nikon P900 with 24mm-2000mm.

How such lenses exist only in point-and-shoot and too at a very low price?
Why does the same equivalent lenses in SLR cost very high?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/why-are-some-lenses-so-expensive

Comment: And http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62196/why-are-some-big-telephoto-lenses-so-expensive-compared-to-telescopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nikon P900 has a 1/2.3" sensor size.

The lenses on these "point-and-shoot" cameras are much smaller, much easier to design and build, and therefore much cheaper. The lenses can be smaller because the sensors are much smaller on point-and-shoot cameras.

[image]
Source: [lensvid.com](https://lensvid.com/technique/why-depth-of-field-is-not-effected-by-sensor-size-a-demonstration/)